# How does thunderbird or android load imap settings automatically

Tags: settings, imap, thunderbird

I would like to know if there is a service out there which can give me imap settings for a given email address. Thunderbird and Android mail clients does a good job if fetching the imap setting automatically when you give the email address.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using popular mail provider (gmail,hotmail, etc) The imap settings are just chosen based on the domain of the email.

If you have your own server, it can't fetch the settings.

Answer (score 0):

To continue on Lauri's answer., it can guess.  If you have an email at @example.com, it will try common things like, mail.example.com, imap.example.com, pop.example.com, smtp.example.com.  etc.  It's all heuristics.